# Explicit example of non constant linear functional $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb Q$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Recall that $V=\mathbb R$ is a uncountably dimension vector space over $\mathbb Q$ as countable dimension vector space over $\mathbb Q$ is itself countable.

> Is there any explicit example of a non constant linear functional $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb Q$ ?

Existence of such linear functional is almost trivial but can we give the explicit example of such $1$-form? Also it is clear that under usual topology such a map $f$ cannot be continuous as $\mathbb Q$ is totally disconnected.

Comment: Nope. You need to make a lot of choices to define such a functional.

Comment: Also your set of vectors is *not* uncountable. You know the dimension of $\mathbb R$ as a vector space over $\mathbb Q$ by Cardinality.

Answer (score 1):

No - the construction of a nonconstant functional $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{Q}$ relies on the axiom of choice, and according to the wikipedia page on [discontinuous linear maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discontinuous_linear_map), there are models of set theory without choice (Solovay's model is an example) in which there are no discontinuous $\mathbb{Q}$-linear maps $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, much less $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{Q}$.